# Fit line to Fourier transform

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

Edit: Added minimal code and further clarification:

Im working with periodic patterns in image space. When we see them in fourier space, I see a cross-like spectrum that gets rotated by the same angle as the specturm in image space.

[image: Image Space]

[image: Magnitude Specturm]

What I have tried:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read Image:
frame=  cv2.imread("ImageSpace.png")[:,:,0]
size= frame.shape[0]
#compute DFT and shift it:
dft=    cv2.dft(np.float32(frame),flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
mag=    cv2.magnitude(dft[:,:,0],dft[:,:,1])
mag=    np.fft.fftshift(mag)
# Filter lower frequencies:
mag[size//2-3:size//2+3,size//2-3:size//2+3]= np.zeros((6,6))
# We focus on the right bottom quadrant for simplification
quarterMag= mag[size//2:,size//2:]
#Search for a local maxima:
XYmax=  np.unravel_index(quarterMag.argmax(), quarterMag.shape)

if XYmax[0]!=0 and XYmax[1]!=0:
    theta_hat= np.arctan(XYmax[1]/XYmax[0])*180/np.pi
else:
    theta_hat= 90


srcTri= np.array([
    [size//2,size//2],
    [size,size//2],
    [size//2,size]
]).astype(np.float32)

dstTri= np.array([
        [size//2,size//2], 
        [size//2-size//2*np.cos(theta_hat*np.pi/180),
        size//2-size//2*np.sin(theta_hat*np.pi/180)],
        [size//2+size//2*np.sin(theta_hat*np.pi/180),
        size//2-size//2*np.cos(theta_hat*np.pi/180)] 
]).astype(np.float32)

warp_Mat=   cv2.getAffineTransform(srcTri, dstTri)
correctedFrame= cv2.warpAffine(frame,warp_Mat,(frame.shape[0],frame.shape[0]))


#Normalize function in order to display it
mag=    cv2.normalize((mag),None,255, 0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8UC1)

cv2.imwrite("CorrectedFrame.png", correctedFrame)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    cv2.imshow("Magnitude Spectrum",mag)
    cv2.imshow("Corrected Frame", correctedFrame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

This code produces this result:

[image: Corrected Image]

My problem is that, due to the fact that I use just the first local maxima to find an angle, I have poor resolution that depends on the resolution of the input image.

For a set of simulated images, I Obtain this result, where the blue continuous line is the angle I rotate and the crosses is the measured angle using this method:

[image: From simulation]

You see that there is a "nonlinear staircaising" effect of about 4-5°.

What I would like to do (or know) is if there is a way of "filtering" only the values in the "main line" in fourier, put them in in a fitLine function so that I get the angle with maximun resolution without increasing the size of input image.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Im sorry if this OT. My reasoning for posting it here its because Im using openCV with python and I was thinking of in the way of doing the computation efficiently. If it is OT then I guess I should move it to Mathematics Stack Exchange

Comment: that spectrum looks a little weird. what exactly are you plotting? [mre] -- usually, with grid patterns, there should be nice local maxima. so your task would be to find local maxima. there's plenty of recipes and ready-made functions out there. *your plot* doesn't look like it has nice local maxima. this may be due to how you create that plot.

Comment: Instead of math or physics I recommend the DSP site.

Comment: I think you'd get somewhere if you "blanked out" the DC component and a bit around it, then look for maxima. don't expect too much accuracy. you'd want to gather multiple local maxima, break all their angles into a 0..90 degree range and average (while minding the wraparound!). this doesn't take theory to get accurate. it's just engineering/programming.

Answer (score 0):

Your **input image resolution** is the main issue behind the quantization of computed angles. You will have to increase the size of dft output, making it more sensitive to smaller frequencies.

Since dft is pixel size invariant (meaning frequencies are in terms of width rather than number of pixels) you cannot simply resize input, but you will have to pad it.

```
pad=250
frame = cv2.copyMakeBorder(frame, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)
```

**Why the 4-5 degree error?**
The local maxima falls only at 27 pixels far from the center, leaving 21 (= 2 π r/4)  pixels for 90 degrees range, giving 4.3 degrees (90/21) gap.